# C++ Dice simulation problem. Im stuck on looping with 2 variables and how this should be formatted

Tags: c++, loops, random, dice

Write a function that simulates two six-sided dice.  Roll both dice and count the number of rolls
it takes to roll a double6 ten times.  Output this message when each double6 is rolled.
double six rolled:  roll #xxxxx
Roll the dice for a maximum of 200000 tries.  For every 10000 roll, a double6 must be rolled.
Display if the double6 was forced.  Stop when double6 is rolled ten times.
Display the number of rolls it took or state that we did not get 10 double6s if we exceed the maximum rolls.

Below are some of my attempts.

```
void rollDice(int numDice = 0)
{
    srand(time(0));
    int die1, die2, maxRoll,doubleSix;
    //die1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
  //  die2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
  // doubleSix = die1 == 6 && die2 == 6; // need a count function for that


   if (die1 == 6 && die2 == 6)
       for (int doubleSix = 0; doubleSix >=10; doubleSix++)
       {
           die1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
           die2 = rand() % 6 + 1;


       }


 //attempt 1
while ( maxRoll <= 200000 || doubleSix == 10)
    if (numDice > 0)
        for (int i = 0; i < numDice; i++) {
            cout << "\nDice roll1" << i + 1 << ": " << die1<<endl;
            cout << "\nDice roll2" << i + 1 << ": " <<die2<<endl;
        }

    else
        cout << "\nExiting.  Next time please enter a value greater than zero and less than 10.\n";

}


 //attempt 2
int i, maxRoll;

maxRoll = 0;
while ( maxRoll < 200000 )
{
maxRoll++;
continue;
cout << "Hello\n";
if ( doubleSix == 10)
break;
}
return 0;
```

Comment: frankly, this looks like you rolled dice to write the code. The first attempt rolls dice in a loop then pritns results in a different infinite loop.... The second has an unconditional `continue` and it is very unclear why it is present

Comment: Well, that's why I'm here asking for help as I'm really not sure how to do it. I am new to this.

Comment: you should explain the code to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). I don't understand any logic of it and I think by going through it line by line while considering what each line is supposed to do you can already find lots of mistakes. As an example consider this condition `while ( maxRoll <= 200000 || doubleSix == 10)` and try to see if it will ever change from `true` to `false`, are you doing anything inside the loop that affects the condition?

Comment: also you need to have a plan before writing the code. Consider what steps are needed to get the result. Once you have a clear idea, you can start writing code. If you start writing code before and try to modifiy it until you get a result without having a clear idea of what the code should do it can easily end in a mess

Comment: To make the code more understandable, `rollDice` should do one and only one thing -- roll a pair of dice, and return the results of each of them.  It shouldn't be doing anything else -- it shouldn't be in the job of seeing if both die are 6, it shouldn't be calculating maximum rolls, none of that.  The functions that call `rollDice` should be in that business.  Start with that simple function `rollDice` to perform one thing, and then branch out from there.  Also, if you are given the task of writing another "pair of dice" game, you can reuse `rollDice` without any changes.

Comment: You have valid points. I will regroup and plan. Your original comment did make me laugh too. Nice play on words.

Comment: There probably should not even be a loop in rollDice(). If you are new you may have a difficulty returning 2 dice rolls from a function.

Comment: `std::pair<int, int> rollDice()` makes more sense.  The return value is a pair that consists of the results of die 1 and die 2.

Comment: i am glad you didn't take the first comment as an offense, it wasn't meant as one ;)

Answer (score 2):

Lets go in tiny steps...

> Write a function that simulates two six-sided dice.

```
std::pair<int,int> rollDice() {
     return { rand() % 6 + 1, rand() % 6 + 1 };
}
```

Thats what you need to get started. Not more.

> Roll both dice and count the number of rolls it takes to roll a double6 ten times

```
int rolls_till_2six() {
     int counter = 0;
     while (true) {
         ++counter;
         auto roll = rollDice();
         if (roll.first == 6 && roll.second == 6) return counter;
     }
}
```

> Output this message when each double6 is rolled. double six rolled: roll #xxxxx

```
int main() {
     srand(time(0));
     int n = rolls_till_2six();
     std::cout << "double six rolled: roll #" << n << "\n";
}
```

> Roll the dice for a maximum of 200000 tries

Now we are going to modify the function above:

```
 std::pair<int,bool> rolls_till_2six(int max_rolls) {
     int counter = 0;
     while (true) {
         ++counter;
         auto roll = rollDice();
         if (roll.first == 6 && roll.second == 6) return {counter,true};
         if (counter == max_rolls) return {counter,false};
     }
}
```

It now returns an `int` and a `bool`. The `bool` indicates whether the double 6 was rolled and the `int` is the number of trials.

> For every 10000 roll, a double6 must be rolled. Display if the double6 was forced.

Ok, so we roll for a maximum of 10000 and if not we "force" a double six:

```
int main() {
     int total = 0;
     int total_max = 200000;
     int n_force = 10000;
     while (total < total_max) {
         auto res = rolls_till_2six(n_force);
         total += total.first;
         if (res.second) {
             // there was a double 6
         } else {
            // there was no double 6
            // ... force it
         }
     }
}
```

I'll stop here. Nothing of this is tested and the last snippet is incomplete. Actually only after writing the answer I realized that I ignored the "to roll a double6 ten times" part of the assignment. However, it wasn't my intention to give away a full solution anyhow. The take away message is: Do things in small steps. Sometimes small steps are still to big, then take tiny steps. Add one thing to your code at a time. And after each tiny step compile the code and perform tests. Do not add more code before you know that the code you already wrote compiles and does the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

Start small, add complications one by one.

First, roll a die.

```
int roll() { return rand() % 6 + 1; }
```

To roll two dice, call it twice.

```
roll();
roll();
```

Count the number of double-sixes.

```
int double6 = 0;
if (roll() == 6 && roll() == 6)
{
    double6 += 1;
    std::cout << "Double six!" << std::endl;
}
```

Repeat counting until ten double-sixes.

```
int double6 = 0;
while (double6 < 10)
{
    if (roll() == 6 && roll() == 6)
    {
        double6 += 1;
        std::cout << "Double six!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Repeat until 200000 rolls *or* ten double-sixes.

```
int rolls = 0;
int double6 = 0;
while (rolls < 200000 && double6 < 10)
{
    rolls += 1;
    if (roll() == 6 && roll() == 6)
    {
        double6 += 1;
        std::cout << "Double six!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Force a double-six every 10000 rolls unless one has occurred.

```
int rolls = 0;
int double6 = 0;
bool got_one = false;
while (rolls < 200000 && double6 < 10)
{
    rolls += 1;
    if (roll() == 6 && roll() == 6)
    {
        double6 += 1;
        std::cout << "Double six!" << std::endl;
        got_one = true;
    }
    if (rolls % 10000 == 0)
    {
        if (!got_one)
        {
            double6 += 1;
            std::cout << "Forced a double six." << std::endl;
        }
        got_one = false;
    }
}
```